# jasmine mocking service inside service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm testing a directive ('planListing') that has a dependency on a service called 'planListingService'. This service has a dependency to another service called 'ajax' (don't shoot the messenger for the bad names).

I'm able to compile the directive, load its scope and get the controller WITH A CAVEAT. As of now I am being forced to mock both services 'planListingService' and 'ajax' otherwise I will get an error like this:

*Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ajaxProvider <- ajax <- planListingService
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=ajaxProvider%20%3C-%20ajax%20%3C-%20planListingService*

I thought that because I was mocking up the 'planListingService' that I wouldn't have to actually bother with any implementation nor any dependencies of this service. Am I expecting too much?

Here is the code in a nutshell:

planListing.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('planListing', planListing)
    .controller('planListingCtrl', PlanListingCtrl);

 function planListing() {
    var varDirective = {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: PlanListingCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: "scripts/directives/planListing/planListing.html";
        }
    };
    return varDirective;
}
PlanListingCtrl.$inject = ['planListingService'];
function PlanListingCtrl(planListingService) {
    ...
}
```

planListingService.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('planListingService', planListingService);
planListingService.$inject = ['$q', 'ajax'];
function planListingService($q, ajax) {
    ...
}
```

ajax.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('ajax', ['backend', '$browser', 'settings', '$http', '$log',
  function (backend, $browser, settings, $http, $log) {
    ...
```

planListing.spec.js

```
describe('testing planListing.js',function(){

    var el,ctrl,scope,vm;
    var service;

    module('myApp');
    module('my.templates');

    beforeEach(module(function ($provide){
        // This seems to have no effect at all, why?
        $provide.service('planListingService', function () {
            this.getAllPricePlans=function(){};
        });
        // I don't get the error if I uncomment this:
        // $provide.service('ajax', function ($q) {
        //  this.getAllPricePlans=function(){};
        // });
    }));

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myApp');
        module('my.templates');
    });

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$compile_,_$rootScope_,_$controller_){
        $compile=_$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        el = angular.element('<plan-listing></plan-listing>');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile(el)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        ctrl = el.controller('planListing');
        scope = el.isolateScope() || el.scope();
        vm = scope.vm;
    }));

    describe('testing compilation / linking', function (){
        it('should have found directive and compiled template', function () {
            expect(el).toBeDefined();
            expect(el.html()).not.toEqual('');
            expect(el.html()).toContain("plan-listing-section");
        });
    });
    it('should have a defined controller',function(){
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should have a defined scope',function(){
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**So why is that I need to mock up the 'ajax' service even though I am mocking up 'planListingService' which is the one calling the 'ajax' service?**

Thanks!

Comment: `ajax` shouldn't be mocked. It should work as you expect. The fact that it injects `ajax` may result from two things: it is injected somewhere else or `planListingService` wasn't mocked. There may be some problems with your tests, the obvious one is that `module('myApp')` should be `beforeEach(module('myApp'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For documentation purposes, here is the answer (thanks @estus for noticing this):

**Indeed the problem was related to the incorrect initialization of my modules. Instead of this:**

```
describe('testing planListing.js',function(){

    var el,ctrl,scope,vm;
    var service;

    module('myApp');
    module('my.templates');
    ...
```

I should've done this:

```
describe('testing planListing.js',function(){

    var el,ctrl,scope,vm;
    var service;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(module('my.templates'));
    ...
```

After that things started working again as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have been there... feels like bad start But i think your directive is depend on the service and you need to inject it in order to directive can work with this, Just by calling directive it doesn't mean that it's going to inject it in your test. It will look for it and if it's not injected it will give you error

you could do so before testing your directive

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
 yourService = $injector.get('yourService');
})
```

Comment: In fact, it does mean that it will be injected. Directive controller depends on `planListingService` and injects the instance.